# libfaketime doesn't work with golang

Tags: ubuntu, go, supervisord

I would like my go program, which runs on ubuntu server (14.04), daemonized with supervisor, to use a fake server time.

In my supervisor config, I use this as the executing command:

`"faketime 'last Friday 5 pm' /home/user/main"`

The program runs, but displays the current time.

According to this article:
[Changing what time a process thinks it is with libfaketime](http://archive09.linux.com/feature/147801)

> libfaketime cannot be used with statically linked or setuid programs, because LD_PRELOAD is not available to such programs.

Is there anyway to have my compiled go program use the faketime?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is that `faketime` uses the `LD_PRELOAD` environment variable to instruct the program's dynamic loader to load `libfaketime` at startup. `libfaketime` will do what's called "interpositioning" - replacing normal dynamic library routines with its own copies of those routines - so that when future dynamic library calls are made, `libfaketime` can influence what happens. In particular, `libfaketime` interposes time-related calls, and thus it is able to return fake values to the program.

The reason that this works for most programs is that they use `libc` to make syscalls. `libc` provides high-level functions for interacting with syscalls, making it easier to do systems programming. In most languages that use `libc`, binaries are dynamically linked, meaning that `libc` isn't actually included in the binary, but rather it is expected that a compiled version of `libc` (called an "object file") will exist on the system when the binary is run, and the dynamic library can be loaded at that point. This dynamic loading is what makes `faketime` possible by way of the `LD_PRELOAD` directive, which changes the loader's behavior.

Go, however, differs in two ways. First, it is statically linked, and thus there is no loader that could ever pay attention to `LD_PRELOAD`. Second, it doesn't use `libc`, so even if it were dynamically linked, and the `LD_PRELOAD` trick worked, `libc` would never be called anyway, so it still wouldn't actually accomplish the intended goal of tricking the program into using fake time functions.

Comment: Go compiler produces dynamically linked binaries by default (unless instructed otherwise). Just do `ldd` and you will see that the binary is linked to `libc.so` (tested on Linux). The difference is that the go packages it depends on, are bundled in the binary. But not the system libraries.