# Is there a libfaketime alternative for Golang?

Tags: testing, go, operating-system

I want to automate some tests where I have to manipulate the system time to check for authentication behaviours of a program that is written in golang. According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36024872/libfaketime-doesnt-work-with-golang/), libfaketime does not work with golang. Is there another way that I can achieve what I want to do with libfaketime?

Here's a description of what libfaketime does from github.

> libfaketime intercepts various system calls that programs use to retrieve the
>   current date and time. It then reports modified (faked) dates and times (as
>   specified by you, the user) to these programs. This means you can modify the
>   system time a program sees without having to change the time system-wide.

Comment: As you can see by [how it was done for the Go playground](https://blog.golang.org/playground), faking time in Go is no simple task. You might consider altering your design to be more testable, so that it accepts a `time.Time` rather than using `time.Now()` internally.

Comment: This means I won't be able to call the program and manipulate the time externally? My test framework is written in Java, even if I change the source code to accept a `time.Time` I cannot test it from Java.

Comment: Correct. If you're trying to black-box-test a binary that varies its output based on the system clock (in a way you can't just disregard entirely), it's going to be really, really difficult. Maybe you can run it in a VM where you can manipulate the virtual hardware clock somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is none.

You need to use something like [`clockwork`](https://github.com/jonboulle/clockwork) (see [this](https://godoc.org/?q=clock) for more) and explicitly pass "time" implementation around your code.

---

*Update* from 2021-03-01 with a more up-to-date list of options:

- https://github.com/LopatkinEvgeniy/clock
- https://github.com/jonboulle/clockwork
- https://github.com/benbjohnson/clock
- https://github.com/facebookgo/clock
- https://github.com/tkuchiki/faketime
- https://github.com/rzajac/clock

Comment: What if I'm writing end-to-end tests for the program? meaning that I will not be able to access the source code directly, but rather creating user scenarios?

Comment: @emma, no way (almost). The reason is that libfaketime does not intercept syscalls but rather subverts the functions of the standard C library which wrap syscalls. Contrary to C code, Go code on most platforms (except Solaris and Windows) calls the kernel directly. So the two remaining ways are: messing with the kernel somehow and testing your program having it built against a patched Go runtime. The latter is not as hard as it sounds but is still a major undertaking.

Comment: I would add that currently at my \$dayjob we're using `github.com/LopatkinEvgeniy/clock` as it's the only package I know of which is able to mock `time.Ticker` and other timers.

Answer (score -1):

There is [this](https://github.com/tkuchiki/faketime) repository (tkuchiki/faketime) which claims to be able to fake the `time.Now()`-function. I don't know how extensively this works and haven't tested it. But it sounds like it might be a solution to your problem.